# Extract subset of a feed file with custom delimiter and create CSV file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I get a feed file in below format.

```
employee_id||034100151730105|L|
employee_cd||03410015|L|
dept_id||1730105|L|
dept_name||abc|L|
employee_firstname||pqr|L|
employee_lastname||ppp|L|
|R||L|
employee_id||034100151730108|L|
employee_cd||03410032|L|
dept_id||4230105|L|
dept_name||fdfd|L|
employee_firstname||sasas|L|
employee_lastname||dfdf|L|
|R||L|
.....
```

Is there any easy unix script to extract **subset** of fields and create a **CSV** like below..

```
employee_cd,employee_firstname,dept_name
03410015,pqr,abc
03410032,sasas,fdfd
.....
```

Comment: Yes there is. Have you made any attempt in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ***awk*** solution (considering that `dept_name` item always goes before `employee_firstname` item):

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=","; print "employee_cd,employee_firstname,dept_name";}
     $1~/employee_cd|employee_firstname|dept_name/{ a[++c]=$3 }
     END { for(i=1;i<length(a);i+=3) print a[i],a[i+2],a[i+1] }' file
```

The output:

```
employee_cd,employee_firstname,dept_name
03410015,pqr,abc
03410032,sasas,fdfd
```

---

*Solution details:*

- `OFS=","` - setting output field separator
- `$1~/employee_cd|employee_firstname|dept_name/` - if first column matches one of the needed items
- `a[++c]=$3` - capturing an item value indexed by consequent position
- `for(i=1;i<length(a);i+=3) print a[i],a[i+2],a[i+1]` - outputting item values by threes

---

To save the output as `.csv` file:

```
the above command > output.csv
```